# expression syntax for data.table := in R

Tags: r, expression, eval, data.table

I am having some trouble getting an `eval` within `data.table` in R to work with an expression.  Here is some code:

```
dtb = data.table(a=1:100, b=100:1, id=1:10)
dtb[,`:=`(c=a+b, d=a/b),by=id] #this works fine
expr = expression({`:=`(c=a+b, d=a/b)}) #try to couch everything in an expression
dtb[,eval(expr),by=id] #this does not work
Error in `:=`(c = a + b, d = a/b) : 
   unused argument(s) (c = a + b, d = a/b)

expr = expression(`:=`(c=a+b, d=a/b)) #this works fine
dtb[,eval(expr),by=id]
```

Why does including `{}` break this?

Comment: " If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: haha, thanks. actually `eval` *is* the correct way to do things in `data.table` : )

Comment: You're really asking why `dtb[,{\`:=\`(c=a+b, d=a/b)},by=id]` doesn't work, right?

Comment: @GSee: yes, i believe those are equivalent but i just wanted to throw the exact syntax i had in here

Comment: @Alex You've used one of those sinful phrases "does not work".  Try and think how difficult it is to answer when you don't provide the error message or show the expected result vs what you get.  I often read and answer from a phone. Even if i did have an r session to hand I'd feel annoyed I have to go to extra effort to copy and paste it when you could have made it easier to answer, but even then i might see a different wrong answer and it just wastes time.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: sure, let me put in the error message if that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the definition of `:=`:

```
function (LHS, RHS) 
stop(":= is defined for use in j only, and (currently) only once; i.e., DT[i,col:=1L] and DT[,newcol:=sum(colB),by=colA] are ok, but not DT[i,col]:=1L, not DT[i]$col:=1L and not DT[,{newcol1:=1L;newcol2:=2L}]. Please see help(\":=\"). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE.")
```

The assignment of a column doesn't happen within a call of `:=`--the function itself doesn't do anything besides produce an error.  The assignment happens when `[.data.table` detects`j` is an expression of the form `` `:=`(...) `` and then sets everything up for a call to the C code.  When you enclose `expr` in brackets, you're making the first part of the expression `{` instead of `:=`, which passes by the above detection and eventually results in an evaluation of `:=` with arguments `c` and `d`.

I guess that leads to the question, why do you need to enclose it in `{ }`?

Comment: interesting - let's let Dowle confirm this

Comment: i just realized your question was towards me: the reason i enclosed it in `{}` initially was because whenever i work with `data.table` and i have a bunch of expressions it's become habit to enclose them since there are multiple statements. in this case there is only 1 so there is no need.

Comment: +1 With those error msgs and user 57's explanation yes that all fits. Improvement would be to define ':=' with '...' and improve error msg.  You can use {} on the RHS of := and on each RHS in ':='(...). It's because dogroups.c either updates be reference or returns a new data.table, not a mixture of both.

Answer (score 5):

[Issue #376](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/376) to trap the `{` around `:=` has now been implemented in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> o  FR #2496 is now implemented to trap and remove the `{` around `:=` in `j` to obtain desired result. Now, `` DT[,{`:=`(...)}] `` and `` DT[, {`:=`(...)}, by=(...)] `` both work as intended but with a warning. Thanks to Alex for reporting on SO: [expression syntax for data.table := in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541959/expression-syntax-for-data-table-in-r)